# Parsing data to tables in excel

Tags: vba, excel, data-extraction

I need to scrape the data from [this page](http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/2/) into a table format. To give you an idea, Here is what it looks like :

[image: Final Table result]

I want to see there is a way to bring this data into a table format using VBA script in excel. I can write a VBA code to do this by trimming the information into small pieces and placing it in particular cells.

I believe that's not the most efficient way and something tells me there is probably a better method out there that I just don't know off yet. Hence, I am reaching out here.

I wanted to see if you guys know of a method to do this better than trimming and pasting.

Comment: @litelite - I dont have a code yet because I am trying to figure out the most efficient method to do this. I am not really looking for a code either, just the method that I should look into to do this.

Comment: The fasted way is to process everything in memory before pasting it to a sheet. So, you want to grab the entire text you got there and place it into a string variable. Then you start building an array and `split` the string into this two-dimensional array. Finally, you place the array on a sheet... Happy coding!

Comment: you may want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098397/extract-data-from-a-web-page-that-may-not-be-formatted-as-a-table) to give you some ideas, but [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards?lq=1) is better

Comment: @mhyst - Excellent response. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Thanks! I get data extraction, but what I am looking for is a bit more challenging due to a pop-up window which is different for each instance.

Comment: @Ralph - Thanks! I'll give that a try if mhyst's information doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks! I hope you know how to put the data into Excel sheet. Here is more information. Look for my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107574/copy-and-paste-specific-cells-from-one-worksheet-to-another/37172544

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is in JSON format. You have to parse it and then decide in what way you want to present the data in Excel.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba) it is informacion about that: